# Does PHP's curl_reset() close the underlying connection?

Tags: php, curl

I am doing many curl requests to the same server in a loop.

I want to keep using the same curl handle, as this is much faster than closing it with `curl_close()` and getting a new one using `curl_init()` as it keeps the underlying connection open. Reusing the handle is definitely faster.

If I call `curl_reset()` after each request, will this reset the connection and therefore slow down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The [`curl_reset` engine code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/curl/interface.c#L3506-L3527) calls the libcurl method `curl_easy_reset` whose [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_reset.html) explicitly states:

> ... does not change the following information kept in the handle: live connections, the Session ID cache, the DNS cache, the cookies and shares.